# Regarding $\lim \limits_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\left(\frac{x^2z}{x^2+y^2+16z^2}\right)$--is WolframAlpha incorrect?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, wolfram-alpha

$$      \lim_{x,y,z\to 0}         {zx^2\over x^2+y^2+16z^2}$$

So I am trying to evaluate this limit..

To me, by using the squeeze theorem, it seems that the answer must be zero.

I trying using the spherical coordinates, which also gives in the same result.

However, [WolframAlpha says the limit does not exist](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%28x%5E2z%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B16z%5E2%29%2C+%28x%2Cy%2Cz%29-%3E%280%2C0%2C0%29%5D).

Could I know whether I am missing something or WolframAlpha is incorrect?(as it happens occasionally)

Comment: By the way, I can't prove this. But I'm convinced that when computing multivariate limits, WA finds the iterated limits. So even has a confirmation of existence it is very shallow.

Comment: Are you *sure* Wolfram is wrong?  It is doing the limit in complex space $\mathbb C^3$.  You have to *tell* it if you want to restrict to real $x,y,z$.

Comment: @GEdgar: I think what they teach is all about $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram does a *complex* limit, unless you specify otherwise.  See the hint in the very link quoted:

> [image: WA]

But look:
substitute
$$
(x,y,z) = (4it,4t^{3/2},t)
$$
into
$$
{zx^2\over x^2+y^2+16z^2}
$$
to get
$$
\frac{t(-16)t^2}{-16t^2+16t^3+16t^2} = -1
$$
along the whole curve.  So anyone claiming the limit is zero is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $0 \leq \dfrac{|zx^2|}{x^2+y^2+16z^2} \leq |z|$

Comment: Thanks for your input. But that's exactly what I did, which gives me the answer of L=0. I just wanted to clarify that I have the right answer and WolframAlpha is giving out an incorrect answer?

Comment: WA is wrong plenty. But when WA says a limit doesn't exist, that is usually the case. This is the first time I see WA saying a limit doesn't exist when it exists.

Comment: Thanks for that! Guess I learnt a lesson not to always trust WA.. This is interesting as this was my first time trying to evaluate a limit on WA.